# .doc to .pdf avoid titus classification level

Tags: python, pdf, docx

I have many documents .doc to turn into .pdf.
I found a way to do it by first converting .doc to .docx.
Only, my company have a TITUS window popup at the moment of saving to ask for the classification level of the document (Public, Internal, Confidential or Secret). Is there a way to set the value automatically to 'internal'.

Here is my code:

```
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants

# Create list of paths to .doc files
paths = glob('path\\directoryOfDocFile\\*.doc', recursive=True)

def save_as_docx(path):
    # Opening MS Word
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc.Activate()

    # Rename path with .docx
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)

    # Save and Close    
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument
    )
    doc.Close(False)

for path in paths:
    save_as_docx(path)
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: You might want to take a look at using [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto#pywinauto) to drive the pop-up? 

If that's no good, you might need to tell us what TITUS is.

Comment: TITUS is a pop-up that pops at when saving a file under Office. It simply asks for the Classification Level of the document (Public, Internal, Confidential or Secret). 
As I have many files (like thousands) to convert from .doc to .docx, the piece of code above opens as much time this pop-up window, and for now I have to manually press 'Internal' for all of them. I would like it to be automatically if possible

Comment: Did you look at pywinauto?